# Keras model deploy to flask text prediction, but not predicting help me

Tags: flask, keras, model, predict

@app.route('/article//')
def article(id):
    # Create cursor
    mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)

```
# Get article
result = mycursor.execute("SELECT label FROM articles WHERE id = %s", [id])

article = mycursor.fetchone()

features = prepData(article)

prediction = int((np.asscalar(load_model.predict(features)))*100)
return render_template('article.html', article=article, prediction=prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

```
<h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
<small>Written by {{article.author}} on {{article.create_date}}</small>
<hr>
<div>
    {{article.body }}
</div>


<h1>Predicted:</h1>
{{ prediction }}
```

{% endblock %}